# Como usar o Pyinstaller em Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com a estrutura da imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como é que faço para criar um executável para o "Transmorphus.py"?

Já tentei usar o PyInstaller e nunca abre o sistema.

Já pesquisei vários sites mas todos que vi só informa como utilizar o Pyinstaller com um script agora com estrutura, onde tem também a parte visual com o PyQT5 não.

Alguém pode me ajudar nessa jornada?

Tentei usar o comando baseado nas dicas do nosso colega @JeanExtreme002 com o comando abaixo, mas gera o erro da imagem em seguida.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --path=config --path=lib --path=public --path=scd --path=systems --path=ui --path=views Transmorphus.py
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo .SPEC fica da seguinte forma:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['Transmorphus.py'],
             pathex=['config', 'lib', 'public', 'scd', 'systems', 'ui', 'views', 'D:\\Estudos_Oficial\\Python\\Transmorphus'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='Transmorphus',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
```

O que pode estar de errado?

Comment: Descobri o que estava acontecendo do erro e do por que não estar abrindo o sistema. Quando eu crio o executável, eu passo toda a estrutura de pastas e coloco dentro da pasta "dist" ou melhor ainda, pego o executável que está dentro da pasta "dist" e coloco na pasta raiz do meu sistema junto a todas as outras pastas. Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Se o que você quer é gerar um `.exe` empacotando esses diretórios para dentro do programa, você pode utilizar o comando `--paths=<diretório>`. O que esse comando vai fazer é simplesmente "adicionar" o diretório dentro do executável.

Agora, se o seu problema está relacionado a uma falha na importação ao executar o `.exe`, você pode utilizar o comando `--hidden-import=<módulo_ou_pacote>`.

Exemplo: `pyinstaller -F --paths=src --hidden-import=tkinter app.py`

Comment: Uma dúvida.
No caso eu colocaria todos os diretórios com virgula separando tipo assim:
--paths=config, lib, public, systems, ui, views ?

Comment: Sinceramente eu não sei, mas eu costumo colocar o comando "--paths=" para cada diretório.

Comment: Testei colocar vírgula para separar os diretórios e não funcionou. Ele simplesmente junta os nomes caso tente (Exemplo: "subpath/config,lib,public"). Você vai ter que colocar realmente um comando por vez.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta com base nas suas dicas e fiz alguns testes e não funcionou. afff. O que será que pode estar acontecendo?